# How to output new lines or break lines on a CRON JOB using a PHP file

Tags: php, email, output

OK, ... here is the deal. I have already have a php file on my server on the cron job is doing it's job correctly.
I do receive the cron job output by email... that means all the ECHO stuff is being sent after the cron runs.
How to output new lines or break lines on a CRON JOB using a PHP file. That's my question.
I'm doing echo `<br>` and I even tried `\n` and `\r\n`... is there a correct way to do so? Since the email that i receive is just a bunch of text in one single line.
Should i add some headers to it?

Comment: You want the CRON to output the new lines or the email to have the new lines? Show your PHP usage.

Comment: You can use `<br>` tag. See my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "your text \n";
```

Note: Make sure you use `" "`. (Double quotes) instead of single quotes.

OR

try

```
echo "your text " . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: well... that was the issue... dumb me. had to use "\n" instead of '\n'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this this:

```
echo "\r\n Cron Start ::" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "--\r\n";   

echo "\r\n CRON Content \r\n";

echo "\r\n--Cron End ::" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "--\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "your content.<br>";
```

Comment: This wouldn't work on console. Only visible in browser

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
echo "your text <br>";
```